# Recreate Google+ / Google Reader Like Header Nav Bar??? (Android)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've created a header menu that is very similar to the screen shots below for an app that I'm working on. However, I can't quite figure out how to make the buttons always stay flush to the right and the field that the logo is in auto-fill the remaining screen space (ie after a screen rotation).

[Screenshot I](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ZzEHJDQvWg4/TlySCcWuumI/AAAAAAAAAzo/Zde3zQJYN40/s512/20110830_013446.jpg) | [Screenshot II](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6iR6rLt7Y6E/TlySCfKT7BI/AAAAAAAAAzk/X8vQQ2HhQ7E/s512/20110830_013504.jpg)

I'm sure the solution has something to do with the the layout_width attribute but I can't figure out how exactly. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!  They are currently in a RelativeLayout...

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:padding="0px">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/logo" 
        android:layout_width="200sp" 
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:text="Logo" android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/dividerOne" 
        android:layout_width="1px" 
        android:layout_height="50sp" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/logo"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/blockList" 
        android:layout_width="50sp" 
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dividerOne"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/dividerOne"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Block List" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/dividerTwo" 
        android:layout_width="1px" 
        android:layout_height="50sp" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blockList"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/blockList"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Log" 
        android:layout_width="50sp" 
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dividerTwo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/dividerTwo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Log"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `@+id/logo` try adding `android:layout_weight="1"`

You'll also need to change from a `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout`.

See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Comment: It's not letting me use weight as a parameter.  Is that only for LinearLayouts?

Comment: This lead me in the right direction.  I had to make the following changes: 1) use layout_weight (not just "weight"!) 2) change from a RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout 3) remove all of the "layout_toRightOf" and "layout_alignTop" attributes 4) set all heights to fill_parent (for some reason)

Comment: Sorry for my brevity. I did mean layout_weight, glad that got you in the right direction; I also didn't consider the limitation of `layout_weight` (as it applies only to `LinearLayout` and `TableLayout`). It's better to use a LinearLayout in this case anyway as RelativeLayout is a lot more complex and is therefore more taxing on the device. Your layout is obviously a linear set of `View`s and therefore doesn't need that complexity.